# Using a system of non-linear equations to prove an identity

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

Prove that if $3xy + 2yz + z + 1 = 0$ and $3zx + 2z + x + 1 = 0$, then $3xy + 2x + y + 1 = 0$.

I think the solution will involve combining these two equations in some way. I have attempted many possible combinations, such as multiplying i) by $x$, multiplying ii) by $y$ and then subtracting them, but there are always terms which do not cancel out, such as $3x^2y$ in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This is false. Take
$$
(x,y,z)=(2/3,-1/2,-5/12).
$$
Then the first two equations are satisfied, but not the third one.

Comment: I was about to provide a similar answer, with$$(x,y,z)=\left(-1,\frac13,0\right).$$

Comment: Or $(x,y,z)=(0,1/2,-1/2)$.

Comment: Hmm, I see.. Is there an analogous equation that is actually true, one which involves only $x$, $y$, and $xy$?

Comment: @John Well, for example $- 9x^2y - 4xy - 2x + 2y - 1=0$. Just eliminate $z$ from one equation (assuming $2y+1\neq 0$ here).

Comment: If $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are four complex numbers and they are not all equal to $0$, then it is false that, from $3xy+2yz+z+1=0$ and $3zx+2z+x+1=0$, you can deduce that $axy+bx+cy+d=0$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos So there is no equation we can derive about $x$, $y$ without including a term like $x^2y$? Could you elaborate on why this is true? Would it hold if the first equation were $3xy + 2y + z + 1 = 0$ instead?